# JVM Problematic frame - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Error

Tags: java, grails, jvm, fatal-error, jvm-crash

I am getting the following error while running  Grails application:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6df13df3, pid=1516, tid=8592

 JRE version: 7.0_05-b06
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x63df3]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 E:\Workspace\opal\hs_err_pid1516.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

this error comes only when i am accessing the gsp page called show.gsp inside of which it calls template called s2PublicTrainingLifecycleEdit.gsp

following is the content of s2PublicTrainingLifecycleEdit.gsp page.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        }); 
    </script>
    <div class="lifecycle">
        <table class="mar">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="40%"><g:message code="course.lifecycle.label" default="Task" /></th> 
                    <th ><g:message code="course.lifecycle.label" default="Yes" /></th> 
                    <th ><g:message code="course.lifecycle.label" default="No" /></th>
                    <th ><g:message code="course.lifecycle.label" default="NA" /></th>              
                </tr>
            </thead>    
                <tr>
                    <td class="heading_view" colspan="4">
                        <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Scheduling" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="scheduledInMyLearnStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Scheduled in myLearn?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus=='Yes'}" >
                        <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.scheduledInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="scheduledInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>

                    </td>   

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"  class="heading_view">
                        <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Marketing" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Published on Training-Classes?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                        <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus=='Yes'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus}"  />
                            </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value=""  />
                            </g:else>

                            </td>
                        <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus=='No'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus=='NA'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="publishedOnTrainingClassesStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                    </td>   
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="publishedOnJtrainingStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Published on Jtraining?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus=='Yes'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus}"  />
                            </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value=""  />
                            </g:else>

                            </td>
                        <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus=='No'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus=='NA'}" >
                                <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.publishedOnJtrainingStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="publishedOnJtrainingStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                    </td>   
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"  class="heading_view">
                        <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Logistics" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="venueBookedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Venue Booked?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value=""  />                   
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.venueBookedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="venueBookedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="flightTicketsBookedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Flight Tickets Booked?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value=""  />                   
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.flightTicketsBookedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="flightTicketsBookedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Training Room Booking Instructions Emailed?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value=""  />                    
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="trainingRoomBookingInstructionsEmailedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Training Room Booking Instructions Telecommunicated?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value=""  />                   
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="roomBookingInstructionsTelecommunicatedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="trainingInfoEmailedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Training Info Emailed?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value=""  />                   
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingInfoEmailedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="trainingInfoEmailedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus">
                            <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Training Info to Instructor Telecommunicated?" />
                        </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value=""  />                   
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="telecommunicateTrainingInfoToInstructorStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Discount Codes Deactivated?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value=""  />                  
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.discountCodesDeactivatedStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="discountCodesDeactivatedStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"  class="heading_view">
                        <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Post-Training" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Trainees Added in myLearn?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus=='No'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />                    
                    </g:else>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                    </g:if>
                    <g:else>
                        <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                    </g:else>
                </td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="lifecycleStatus">
                        <div class="lifecycleEditLabel">
                            <label for="trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus">
                                <g:message code="publicTraining.course.label" default="Training Closed in myLearn?" />
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus=='Yes'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <g:if test="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus=='NA'}" >
                            <g:checkBox name="trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus" value="${publicTrainingInstance?.s2Publiclifecycle?.trainingClosedInMyLearnStatus}"  />
                        </g:if>
                        <g:else>
                            <g:checkBox name="traineesAddedInMyLearnStatus" value=""  />
                        </g:else>
                    </td>

                </tr>   

        </table>
    </div>
```

Where if i remove last tr of the table application runs fine.. else it gives above error on run time.

**Complete error report**

```
        ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x48ae6400):  JavaThread "http-bio-8080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=8592, stack(0x4f650000,0x4f6a0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x497e1c30

    Registers:
    EAX=0x0000ff08, EBX=0x000000a7, ECX=0x497a2010, EDX=0x07e26112
    ESP=0x4f69ae64, EBP=0x4f69ae68, ESI=0x00000001, EDI=0x00000001
    EIP=0x6df13df3, EFLAGS=0x00010246

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x4f69ae64)
    0x4f69ae64:   07e26112 4f69aea8 6df143a5 07e26112
    0x4f69ae74:   00000001 000008ff 00000002 00000014
    0x4f69ae84:   4f69aee8 000000bb 07e26028 000000ba
    0x4f69ae94:   0000310f 00000000 00000005 4f69aee8
    0x4f69aea4:   000010f7 4f69aec4 6df148b6 07e36b30
    0x4f69aeb4:   00000000 48ae6400 4b34ea18 48ae6858
    0x4f69aec4:   4f69af1c 6df149eb 47c478bc 47c478c4
    0x4f69aed4:   47c478c0 48ae6400 07e3e4a0 47c478bc 

    Instructions: (pc=0x6df13df3)
    0x6df13dd3:   80 7d 10 00 8b 55 08 56 8b 75 0c 0f b7 04 32 75
    0x6df13de3:   1c 89 45 10 66 8b 45 10 86 c4 8b 49 10 0f b7 c0
    0x6df13df3:   66 8b 04 81 66 89 04 32 5e 5d c2 0c 00 8b 49 18
    0x6df13e03:   8b 04 81 c7 45 10 ff ff ff ff a9 00 00 00 40 75 


    Register to memory mapping:

    EAX=0x0000ff08 is an unknown value
    EBX=0x000000a7 is an unknown value
    ECX=0x497a2010 is an unknown value
    EDX=0x07e26112 is an oop
    {constMethod} 
     - klass: {other class}
     - method:       0x07e36b30 {method} 'run' '()Ljava/lang/Object;' in 'E__Workspace_opal_grails_app_views_lifecycle__s2PublicTraininglifecycleEdit_gsp'
     - exceptions:   0x03c41128
    bci_from(07E26112) = 186; print_codes():
    ESP=0x4f69ae64 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x48ae6400
    EBP=0x4f69ae68 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x48ae6400
    ESI=0x00000001 is an unknown value
    EDI=0x00000001 is an unknown value


    Stack: [0x4f650000,0x4f6a0000],  sp=0x4f69ae64,  free space=299k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0x63df3]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x643a5]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x648b6]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x649eb]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x8dcb3]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x93fe8]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x9549c]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xea44a]
    j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+0
    j  java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+81
    j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+10
    j  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredConstructors(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+10
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+10
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    V  [jvm.dll+0x13bd4a]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x1f358e]
    V  [jvm.dll+0x13bdcd]
    V  [jvm.dll+0xe4f0a]
    C  [java.dll+0x1015]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2+0x15
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedConstructor;+8
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2.initValue()Ljava/lang/Object;+1

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+0
    j  java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Z)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+81
    j  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+10
    j  com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredConstructors(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;+10
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$2$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+10
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j       J  
    Dynamic libraries:
    0x00400000 - 0x0042f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java.exe
    0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
    0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
    0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
    0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
    0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
    0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
    0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
    0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
    0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
    0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
    0x78aa0000 - 0x78b5e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
    0x6deb0000 - 0x6e3e3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
    0x71ad0000 - 0x71ad9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
    0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
    0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
    0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
    0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
    0x6d950000 - 0x6d95c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\verify.dll
    0x6d400000 - 0x6d420000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\java.dll
    0x6d3b0000 - 0x6d3d0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\instrument.dll
    0x6d9a0000 - 0x6d9b3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\zip.dll
    0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
    0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
    0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
    0x6d720000 - 0x6d734000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\net.dll
    0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
    0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
    0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
    0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
    0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
    0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
    0x6d740000 - 0x6d74f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\nio.dll
    0x47bc0000 - 0x47c14000     C:\Documents and Settings\Hussain\Local Settings\Temp\jna8999333547967723157.dll
    0x48e30000 - 0x48e38000     C:\Documents and Settings\Hussain\Local Settings\Temp\jline_.dll
    0x6d8c0000 - 0x6d8e0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\sunec.dll
    0x6d8e0000 - 0x6d8e9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
    0x77a80000 - 0x77b15000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
    0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
    0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
    0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
    0x6d680000 - 0x6d68a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\management.dll
    0x59a60000 - 0x59b01000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll
    0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -javaagent:E:/springsource/grails-2.0.4/bin/../lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.5.jar -Xverify:none -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Dprogram.name= -Dgrails.home=E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\.. -Dgrails.version=2.0.4 -Dbase.dir=. -Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf 
    java_command: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin\..\conf\groovy-starter.conf --classpath   run-app
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
    PATH=C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;4.3632E+222RAILS_HOME\bin;E:\springsource\grails-2.0.4\bin;C:\xampplite\php;C:\xampplite\htdocs\cakephp\app\Console;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\testApp\lib\Cake\Console;E:\program FilesGroovy-1.8.6\bin;E:\jboss\apache-ant-1.8.4/bin
    USERNAME=Hussain
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

    CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

    Memory: 4k page, physical 3072196k(507880k free), swap 5003920k(1202460k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (23.1-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_05-b06), built on Jun 27 2012 00:48:44 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

    time: Mon Jul 30 11:52:27 2012
    elapsed time: 1039 seconds
```

Comment: is it possible that the application's classes were compiled with a different JDK version? Do you still experience the issue after cleaning the application and then running the run-app command?

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your JVM to 1.6 not 1.7.

Comment: why is that ? How can it be overcome by having JVm 7

Comment: I personally had problems with grails on JVM1.7 early version. Perhaps it's gone with recent updates. But problems gone switching back to 1.6